# Ubuntu via UTM on M1 not showing shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, arm, virtual-machine, apple-m1, utm

I have an M1 macbook pro, using Ubuntu via UTM virtual machine but when I open files application and press "Other Locations" I only see computer and Windows Network but it won't show me the shared folder I set on the virtual machine.
How do I make the set folder on osx appear in virtual machine Ubuntu?

I tried looking at other tutorials and posts like this in different forums, I did find similar problems to this but not the same. I also realized that the problem might just be with using arm which already made the installing process of Ubuntu more challenging, yet don't manage to find a solution for this.

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, Stack Overflow is not the right site for it.  [Apple.SE] might be, but read its posting guidelines carefully before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the SPICE WebDAV utilities.  It's all in the DOCS:
https://docs.getutm.app/settings-qemu/sharing/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).